# Transform JSON Dataframe/RDD schema in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am seeking help in transforming a JSON dataframe/Rdd from one schema structure to another. I am looking at more than 100,000 rows of json data being read and would like to transform that data before inserting into a document store. I am performing the transformations in Spark using scala. Currently i am using json4s framework to parse one json row at a time and transforming it before inserting into the document store, which is not leveraging the power of Spark processing. I would like to transform all the data together, which I believe will speed up the processing.

Following is a code snippet to illustrate my problem.

My input data looks like the **inpString** string, with multiple rows of JSON.

```
val inpString= """[{
"data": {
"id": "1234",
"name": "abc",
"time": "2015-01-01 13-44-21",
"x": [
  50,
  10
],
"y": [
  100,
  20
],
"z": [
  150,
  30
],
"x_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
],
"y_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
],
"z_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
]
}},
{
"data": {
"id": "1235",
"name": "cde",
"time": "2015-01-01 3-21-01",
"x": [
  50,
  10
],
"y": [
  100,
  20
],
"z": [
  150,
  30
],
"x_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
],
"y_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
],
"z_limit": [
  70,
  90,
  15,
  20
]
}}]"""
```

I read it into a dataframe and am able to select, groupby and do all other operations using Sparksql.

```
val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(inpString::Nil)
val inputDf = sqlContext.read.json(inputRDD)
inputDf.printSchema()
```

Schema looks like below

```
root
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- x: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- x_limit: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- y: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- y_limit: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- z: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- z_limit: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

The **x** array in my input data has two types of readings(say type1 and type2) and the **x_limit** array has the lower and upper limits for the two types of readings in **x** array. **x_limit[0]** is the lower limit for type1, **x_limit[1]** is the upper limit for type1, **x_limit[2]** is the lower limit for type2 and **x_limit[3]** is the upper limit for type2. I need to group all the data for type1 together in one struct and all the data for type2 in one struct.

Following code snippet will give us the output schema

```
val outString= """[{
  "data": {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "abc",
    "time": "2015-01-01 13-44-21",
    "type1": {
     "x_axis" : 50,
     "y_axis" : 100,
     "z_axis" : 150,
     "x_lower_limit" : 70,
     "x_upper_limit" : 90,
     "y_lower_limit" : 70,
     "y_upper_limit" : 90,
     "z_lower_limit" : 70,
     "z_upper_limit" : 90
    },
    "type2": {
     "x_axis" : 10,
     "y_axis" : 20,
     "z_axis" : 30,
     "x_lower_limit" : 15,
     "x_upper_limit" : 20,
     "y_lower_limit" : 15,
     "y_upper_limit" : 20,
     "z_lower_limit" : 15,
     "z_upper_limit" : 20
    }
  }
},
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1235",
    "name": "cde",
    "time": "2015-01-01 3-21-01",
    "type1": {
     "x_axis" : 50,
     "y_axis" : 100,
     "z_axis" : 150,
     "x_lower_limit" : 70,
     "x_upper_limit" : 90,
     "y_lower_limit" : 70,
     "y_upper_limit" : 90,
     "z_lower_limit" : 70,
     "z_upper_limit" : 90
    },
    "type2": {
     "x_axis" : 10,
     "y_axis" : 20,
     "z_axis" : 30,
     "x_lower_limit" : 15,
     "x_upper_limit" : 20,
     "y_lower_limit" : 15,
     "y_upper_limit" : 20,
     "z_lower_limit" : 15,
     "z_upper_limit" : 20
    }
  }
}
]"""

    val outputRDD = sc.parallelize(outString::Nil)
    val outputDf = sqlContext.read.json(outputRDD)
    outputDf.printSchema()
```

Output Schema

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_axis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_lower_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z_upper_limit: long (nullable = true)
```

I did some research to find for a similar scenario but could not. I appreciate your inputs.